# React-Redux: Connect syntax with vs without decorator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm wondering what's the difference between these two blocks of code. Do they work differently because I haven't got some syntax right somewhere, or are they fundamentally different?

Without the decorator I get:

`Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop 'actions' was not specified in 'MainSection'`

**With Decorator**

```
@connect(
  state => ({
   notes: state.notes,
   activeNote: state.activeNote,
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(NoteActions, dispatch)
  })
)

export default class Main extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    notes: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    activeNote: PropTypes.object,
    // actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const { notes, activeNote, NoteActions } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={style.normal}>
        <MainSection actions={NoteActions} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Without Decorator**

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    notes: state.notes,
    activeNote: state.activeNote,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    NoteActions
  }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: The difference I see in your code is that in your 'without decorator' code you're passing `NoteActions` as an object.. but in your decorator you're passing it as an argument, not wrapped in an object

Comment: Thanks for your input. How should I be formatting it?

Trying this leads to the same issues: `const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    NoteActions
  , dispatch);
};`

Comment: Why don't you return the exact same thing you have in your decorator? `const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(NoteActions, dispatch)
  }
};`

Comment: I didn't realize I could do it that way, but that too produces the same error. I can't understand how it differs from the decorator, but I'm having trouble that I believe is related to the decorator in production. It works fine in development.

Comment: Scratch that. Found a typo. It works now. No idea if I have solved the issue I intend to, but thanks very much for your help in getting this vital piece of troubleshooting underway!